# PHP cURL, just shows garbled text on page

Tags: php, curl

I am trying to download a file over cURL and save it to a file, but it just displays the page all garbled, I believe it's showing the contents of the file. I would use fopen, but I'm hoping to allow it to follow redirects.

```
<?php
$url = $_POST["url"];
If(empty($url)){header('Location: index.php'); exit;}
$email = $_POST["email"];
$domain = $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'];

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS, 3);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 0);
$dl = curl_exec($ch);
$filename = basename($url);
echo "Downloading $url "; 
echo "<br>";
echo "to ";
echo "<br>";
$downloadedto = 'http://' . $domain . '/downloads/' . $filename;

echo "<a href='$downloadedto'>$downloadedto</a>";



file_put_contents("downloads/$filename", $dl, 'r', LOCK_EX);
If(!empty($email)){
mail ($email, "Your cloud download is complete!", "Good news! Your cloud download of $filename is finished!, please download it soon before it is auto deleted from our server $downloadedto");
}
?>
```

Comment: Does setting `CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER` option help? curl_exec by default returns only true/false

Comment: i think you will need curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); Dont know if it solves your problem, but this way curl will return true not the content for the file.  http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-exec.php

Comment: @VA79 That worked thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Finwe and @VA79 pointed out I needed `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);` as by default cURL only returns true/false rather than the data :)